# silex send parameters between controllers

Tags: php, silex

i need to send an array between 2 controlles (and twig)

in the first controller i have this "if":

```
if ($userverification) {
        $subRequest = Request::create('/reservation/login', 'POST', $pippo = array('pippo' => 'pippo' ));
        return $app->handle($subRequest, HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST);
```

and in the second this:

```
$app->POST('/reservation/login', function (Request $request) use ($app) {
    var_dump($pippo);
});
```

but (obviously) doesn't work, i want to redirect the browser to /reservation/login and take the $pippo array, is it possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the Request's "attributes" to pass the data between the two request, that's good. But you don't retrieve it on `/reservation/login`.

```
$pippo = $request->attributes->get('pippo');
```